# Get the title of a selectable item in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a list of selectable buttons, whose names are being dynamically generated by reading from a JSON file. Every time a button is clicked, I want the get its title, i.e. row["name"]. Here's my relevant code and the JSON:

```
<head>


          <script>

                $.getJSON("json-data.txt",function(data){
                    var items = [];
                    $.each(data['data'],function(i, row){
                        items.push("<li class = 'ui-widget-content'>" + row["name"] + "</li>");
                    });
                    $("<ol/>",{
                        "id" : "selectable",
                        html : items.join("")
                    }).appendTo("body");
                });

                var selectableObj = {
                    selected: function(event, ui){ 

                    }
                }

                $(function() {
                    $( "#selectable" ).selectable(selectableObj);
                });
          </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
```

The JSON data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "ABC",
      "visited" : "Yes"
    },
    {
      "name": "DEF",
      "visited" : "Yes"
    },
    {
      "name": "GHI",
      "locked": "No"
    },
],

}
```

This works, in that I get a list of selectables in the format:

```
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">ABC</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">DEF</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">GHI</li>
</ol>
```

When I click on, say, the first button, I want to get the value "ABC". I don't know how to do this. I read about .text(), but cannot understand to use it. Can anyone help please?

EDIT - Based on some comments, I changed my code like this, but it doesn't work:

```
<script>

                $(function() {
                    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
                });

                $.getJSON("json-data.txt",function(data){
                    var items = [];
                    $.each(data['data'],function(i, row){
                        items.push("<li class = 'ui-widget-content'>" + row["name"] + "</li>");
                    });
                    $("<ol/>",{
                        "id" : "selectable",
                        html : items.join("")
                    }).appendTo("body");
                });


                $('.ui-widget-content').click(function(){
                    var text = $(this).text(); // this get the text
                    alert(text); // do whatever you want with it
                });             
          </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for

```
selected: function() {
        $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
          alert($(this).text());
        });
      }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0t68g2j0/)

Comment: is there a way to do it dynamically, i mean instead of 1,2, etc.. use i, for the ith button?

Comment: @user3033194 I think lmgonzalves answer is what you need .. if its not .. tell me what you want to do exactly

Comment: Imgonzalves' answer is correct, but with selectable it doesn't work, or at least I don't know where to put it in the code for selectableObj.

Comment: Your answer is right also, but with that it shows the first name for every button in the list I click. I want ABC to be displayed for the first button, DEF for the second, and so on..

Comment: @user3033194 yes :)  .. Good Luck to you

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#selectable').on('click', 'li', function(evt){
    var text = $(this).text();
    console.log(text);
});
```

The explanation is of how this works is that it attaches a click event to the parent of the list item, which is `#selectable` in the code you provided. Binding an event to the parent element attaches one event to the DOM *in total* instead of attaching an event for every list item, so it is very efficient. This concept is known as event delegation.

The function that appears inside of `on()` uses the `$(this)` selector,  which makes sure you are getting the text of the item that has been clicked upon only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('.ui-widget-content').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).text(); // this get the text
    alert(text); // do whatever you want with it
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/pqo1r96p/

**EDIT:**

Please try this way instead:

```
$('body').on('click', '.ui-widget-content', function(){
    var text = $(this).text(); // this get the text
    alert(text); // do whatever you want with it
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/pqo1r96p/1/

Comment: Is it possible to put this inside the selectableObj var for "selected"? I understand this works, but with selectable it doesn't.